# Which font should I use to display all Chinese characters?

Tags: unicode, fonts

I want to display chinese character [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_elements_in_East_Asian_languages#Recently_discovered_elements).
I installed HanaMinA, HanaMinB but these characters are not displayed.
Which font should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize the Chinese characters for these recently discovered chemical elements by installing the free [BabelStone Han](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) font.

[Download](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html#Download) links can be found at the bottom of the page, and the most appropriate is possibly this *Serif* one (2020-07-19):

https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Download/BabelStoneHanPlain.zip

**Edit**: these Unihan characters are also available in multiple formats in the five different CJK typefaces belonging to the open-source set of *Sans-Serif* [Google Noto CJK Fonts](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk).